# Big-O (Space Complexity)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o, space-complexity

Most articles you’ll read on the subject of **Big-O** all or the majority of the time covering **time complexity** and if they do mention **space complexity** at all, it’s pretty much a footnote.
Why space complexity gets this behavior?

I tried many resource but there were very little explanation about space complexity.

Comment: Often space is not so limited. But in some cases space complexity is relevant and therefore considered. e.g for algorithms in DNA sequence alignment space is often limited to O(n) so dynamic programming with naive O(n^2) space complexity is not feasible because n is too big.

Comment: I wish it got more attention. I often see problems in web applications where the programmer uses a DOM like parser to process some file and loads O(N) data into memory, then the server crashes by running out of RAM, because N users will give you O(N^2) RAM use.
But if they used streams correctly they could use O(1) RAM to process the request, and then O(N) users would only use O(N) memory. Memory is very important

Comment: Another problem I see is that when using certain ORMs with caches, developers aren't careful and end up serializing too much. So again you end up with an O(N^2) type situation or worse. These things have huge impact on web apps.

Answer (score 0):

Because in current scenario space in electronic devices is continuously increasing , but users want their queries to be responded as fast as possible.So time is more prioritized than space while writing an application .

Comment: Also the speed of devices is continuously increasing.